# Revert all commits from branch after merging into master

Tags: git, github

Few months ago I did lots of changes in my code and pushed it into master.

Now I need to remove all the changes I made, and pushing the initial state of the branch back to master.

I'm confused with all the commands and don't wanna mess my git, How can I reset a branch to his initial state?

Comment: If you do a `git log` in your repository, do you see the latest commit you want to keep in your branch? In other words, did you only add commits on top of the state you want to restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new days, you can get the working tree just like a previous revision (or actually, any revision... even from other branches) using `restore`:

```
git restore --staged --worktree --source=<the-revision> -- .
```

Then, you can commit with whatever you think makes sense:

```
git add . # maybe this is not needed because I used --staged, but I am not that familiar with the UI so....
git commit -m "Taking it back to how it was back then"
```

The old way would take a few steps, but it works just as easily, no hassle:

```
git checkout the-commit-with-content-I-want
git reset --soft the-branch-where-i-want-it
git commit -m "Taking it back to blahblah"
# now you have a revision past the-branch-i-want
# check that you like what you see in history with git log and stuff.... also check files contents and so on
# when you are confident, move the branch pointer:
git branch -f the-branch-where-i-want-it
git checkout the-branch-where-i-want-it
```

And you are done

Answer (score 2):

Another way to "reset" a branch back to some earlier state *and not modify any of the existing history* is to use `git apply` being fed the output from a diff:

```bash
git checkout master
git status # Should report "nothing to commit, working tree clean"
git diff HEAD initial-state-of-the-branch-commit | git apply -
git commit -m "Reset back to initial state of the branch" -m "Using command: git diff HEAD initial-state-of-the-branch-commit | git apply -"
```